# RVIZ wrench display type missing

Tags: ros, rviz, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running rviz version 1.9.29 but do not have this display type:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Wrench
How do I enable it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64074/rviz-wrench-display-type-missing/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the Wrench type was added very recently ( https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/commit/e04d803f50fb33cb0bde6590a770fedbe0fb9940 ), and was released for deb build about a day ago.

You have a few options:

- Build the latest rviz from source
- Switch to using the unstable deb repository, which has the latest debs but tends to be incomplete
- Wait a week or two for the latest version to make it into the stable repository

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1